# Position of page numbers

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I want to move the position of my page numbers to the bottom right of the page.  Is there a way to do it *without* using the `fancyhdr` package?

Right now I just use

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

and it does the job, but the default setting is to put the page number in the bottom middle. If it makes a difference, I am using TeXworks.

Comment: Any reason to not using `fancyhdr` package? Also what `documentclass` are you using?

Comment: I am using \documentclass{article}

Answer (score 6):

I assume, you are using pagestyle `plain`. The original definition can be found
in [source2e](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf). It can be changed from centering to right aligning the page number:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\ps@plain}{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{%
    \reset@font
    \hfil
    \thepage
    % \hfil % removed for aligning to the right
  }%
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Remarks:

- Some document classes might already contain support for configuring the footer.
- The page headers and footers can be configured via package `fancyhdr` or package `scrpage2` (from `KOMA-Script`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, even though I was using the fancyhdr package. The key is to use the

```
\fancyhf{}
```

tag before you use

```
\begin{document}
```

if you are using fancyhdr and still getting enumeration for the page numbers in the center of your footer. You can also use the command

```
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
```

to put the page number in the upper righthand side of the page in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is actually easiest to just use \usepackage{fancyhdr}. Added this code and everything works like a charm.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
\rfoot{\thepage}
```

Comment: You *must* require something else to actually set the page number in the footer, right? Something like `\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}`.