# How to reposition or remove middle pagination labels?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

Right now, I am using the following fancy headers as required by my school's department policy. However, when I look at the footer, it has a number for each page in the middle of my footer label. I want to move the page number to the bottom right or completely remove it from the bottom middle of the footer. I added the page number to the top right, which I like, but it still remains in the bottom middle as well. I followed the steps on this page: [Position of page numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82753/position-of-page-numbers)

but it only removes my current header/footer information, which is not helpful. I only want to remove the page lettering in the bottom middle of the page. Here is the code I'm using currently for my fancy header/footer.

This part is in the package inclusion area:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%For headers/footers
\pagestyle{fancy} %%For fancy headers
```

This part is in the document:

```
\fancyhead[L]{M 414 - DETERMINISTIC MODELS } %%Header
\rhead{Lecture Notes}
\fancyfoot[L]{NAME INFO - UNIVERSITY OF MONTUCKY: MATH DEPARTMENT} %Footer
\rhead{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

%Fix headers on Table of Contents and List of Figures:
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{M 414 - DETERMINISTIC MODELS} %%Header
\fancyhead[R]{Lecture Notes}
\fancyfoot[L]{NAME INFO - UNIVERSITY OF MONTUCKY: MATH DEPARTMENT} %Footer
\rhead{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}

\rhead{\thepage}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Probably this code is what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%For headers/footers

\usepackage{blindtext} % only for the example


\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{M 414 - DETERMINISTIC MODELS} %%Header
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{NAME INFO - UNIVERSITY OF MONTUCKY: MATH DEPARTMENT} %Footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\pagestyle{fancy} %%For fancy headers


%Fix headers on Table of Contents and List of Figures:
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

In the code, `\fancyhf{}` clears the contents of both header and footer, so that with the lines

```
\fancyhead[L]{M 414 - DETERMINISTIC MODELS} %%Header
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{NAME INFO - UNIVERSITY OF MONTUCKY: MATH DEPARTMENT} %Footer
```

you can add what you want at specific places.

The line

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
```

is to make `plain` pages have the same headers and footers as `fancy` ones.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. I was able to narrow it down even further. I kept everything in my code EXACTLY how it was and commented out parts of your code until I found the one piece that made it work.

The key is this: 

    \fancyhf{}

Which needs to precede 

    \begin{document}

Originally, my code had that \fancyhf{} tag, but it followed my \begin{document} tag, so it didn't work correctly. Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: @Blairg23 Happy to help.

Comment: Can you vote up my question/answer if you haven't already? I am just shy of being able to upvote other peoples' answers.

Comment: @Blairg23 I've upvoted both your question and your answer. Now, if you want, you can upvote mine. :-)

Answer (score 1):

karlkoeller had the correct idea.

I was able to narrow it down even further. I kept everything in my code EXACTLY how it was and commented out parts of your code until I found the one piece that made it work.

The key is this:

```
\fancyhf{}
```

Which needs to precede

```
\begin{document}
```

Originally, my code had that

```
\fancyhf{}
```

tag, but it followed my

```
\begin{document}
```

tag, so it didn't work correctly. Everything works perfectly now with the simple addition of the

```
\fancyhf{}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    \pagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \lhead{M 414 - DETERMINISTIC MODELS} %%Header
    \rhead{Lecture Notes\quad\thepage}%
    \cfoot{\small NAME INFO - UNIVERSITY OF MONTUCKY: MATH DEPARTMENT} %Footer
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}%
     }%
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with \fancyfoot . I kind of like the line separating the paper from the footer. Is there a way to do that or is \cfoot the only resolution?